# Chrome Extension - Load new page in current tab

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I am trying to load another page when a button is clicked in my Chrome Extension.

My manifest is like this with the permissions set.

```
{
  "name": "Getting Started Example",
  "description": "Build an Extension!",
  "version": "1.0",
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "background" : {
    "service_worker": "background.js"
  },
  "permissions": ["storage", "activeTab","tabs", "scripting"],
  "action": {
    "default_popup": "popup.html",
    "default_icon": {
      "16": "/images/get_started16.png",
      "32": "/images/get_started32.png",
      "48": "/images/get_started48.png",
      "128": "/images/get_started128.png"
    }
  },
  "icons": {
    "16": "/images/get_started16.png",
    "32": "/images/get_started32.png",
    "48": "/images/get_started48.png",
    "128": "/images/get_started128.png"
  }
}
```

My js to change the page is like this. The first alert shows, but the page doesn't load and the second alert does not show.

```
function changePage() {
       var newUrl = "https://www.bbc.co.uk";
       alert("changePage1");
       chrome.tabs.update({url: newUrl});
       alert("changePage2");
        
  }
```

After the first alert shows, nothing happens

Comment: see [chrome.tabs.update](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/tabs/#method-update) documentation

Comment: Thanks @Robbi. I have looked at that and believe I am doing it correctly. I have also tried passing undefined as the first parameter but it makes no difference.

Comment: Your code is correct and it's working for me. Remove `alert` and use devtools for full debugging experience. Note that the popup is a separate window so it has its own separate devtools: right-click inside the popup and select "inspect" in the menu.

Comment: Are you injecting this code via executeScript? If so, it runs as a content script and can't use chrome.tabs API, but you can use location.href = newUrl instead.